# What functions in python matplotlib or seaborn to customize each box in the heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

This figure seems to be generated using python seaborn. But how exactly is each box customized with different shape (star or dot) and background color (size)?

[image: xx]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the graph in question was created in the R language 'ggplot2'.
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196756/significance-level-added-to-matrix-correlation-heatmap-using-ggplot2),[Correlation Heatmaps in R](https://jkzorz.github.io/2019/06/11/Correlation-heatmaps.html)
The Python seaborn provides the following customization examples.[Better Heatmaps and Correlation Matrix Plots in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/better-heatmaps-and-correlation-matrix-plots-in-python-41445d0f2bec)

The process I found this answer is to search for the posted image in Google (by right-clicking on it) I'm checking out each of these sites, and I encourage you to take a look at them as well. If you've already searched and posted on our site, you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it is R.